# Location of PFILE in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Where is the Parameter File/P FILE stored in Oracle?

In what section is it stored? Is it stored with the data files or stored separately?

If separately, then where is it actually stored on the database?

Comment: It's on disk. Have a look at the Oracle reference for [`CREATE PFILE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6008.htm#SQLRF01308).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it stored with the data files or stored separately? If separately then where is it actually stored on the database.

By default, **PFILE** is located in `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs`.

Read more about it here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6008.htm#SQLRF01308